# split dataset into train and test using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, train-test-split

I want to split my full dataset(every raw data has multiple features) into train and test sets. Rather than using scikit-learn 's train-test-split is there any other proper way to split my data? as well as I need to shuffle my data when splitting.
(If the suggested method is based on tensorflow, it's too better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.random.uniform([100, 5], 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)
input = tf.random.shuffle(input)
train_ds = input[:90]
test_ds = input[-10:]
```